# MongoDB get documents with at least one not empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My schema:

```js
    db.Interactives = mongoose.model(
        'Interactives',
        new Schema({
            url: String,
            forms: Array,
            inputs: Array,
            textareas: Array,
        })
    );
```

I want to find all documents where at least one array isnt empty, so I tried:

```js
    await db.Interactives.find({
            $elemMatch: {
                forms: { $ne: [] },
                inputs: { $ne: [] },
                textarea: { $ne: [] },
            },
        })
            .select('-_id -__v')
            .exec()
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that it is trying make sure no arrays are empty.  The other issue is that `$elemMatch` searches elements of an array for a value.  You don't want to do that, you want to compare the array with a blank array.  The only change you have to make is replace `$elemMatch` with `$or` and add brackets like so

```
    await db.Interactives.find({
            $or: [
                {forms: { $ne: [] }},
                {inputs: { $ne: [] }},
                {textarea: { $ne: [] }},
            ]
        })
            .select('-_id -__v')
            .exec()
```

Answer (score 1):

**What you missed is `$or` in your query.**

Also it can be done in many ways.
Suppose this is your data set.

```
[
  {"Id_Cust": "4145","firstName": "Albade","language": ["English,Nepali"],"degree": []},
  {"Id_Cust": "5296","firstName": "Rafael","language": [],"degree": ["Bachelor,Masters"]},
  {"Id_Cust": "6192","firstName": "Abdul","language": [],"degree": []}
]
```

Now, you can do:

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {language: {$exists: true,$not: {$size: 0}}},
    {degree: {$exists: true,$not: {$size: 0}}}
  ]
})
```

If your fields in array are optional fields use `$exists` otherwise you can exclude it.

**Alternative I**

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {language: {$ne: []}},
    {degree: {$ne: []}}
  ]
})
```

If your fields in array are optional fields use `$exists` just like in the above query.

**Alternative II**

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {language: {$gt: []}},
    { degree: {$gt: []}}
  ]
})
```

If your fields in array are optional fields use `$exists` just like in the very first query.

All methods gives same **output**:

```
[
  {
    "Id_Cust": "4145",
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "degree": [],
    "firstName": "Albade",
    "language": [
      "English,Nepali"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id_Cust": "5296",
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "degree": [
      "Bachelor,Masters"
    ],
    "firstName": "Rafael",
    "language": []
  }
]
```

So, you can do it in any way.